# 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, selenium

Я делал бота для сайта который первым делом должен войти в учётную запись по нажатию на кнопку, однако когда я прописал то что хочу и запустил код мне выдало ошибку: 'str' object is not callable

Я хочу чтобы произвёлся клик по кнопке

Вот мой код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = "https://omlet.gg/stream/iromanenkov"

# Указываем абсолютный путь до хромдрайвера
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\namva\PycharmProjects\seleniumlessons\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")

try:
    driver.get("https://omlet.gg/stream/iromanenkov")
    time.sleep(5)
    # Логин
    login = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME(" omlet-bar-login-button")).click()
    time.sleep(5)



except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("omlet-bar-login-button").click()
```

Ну либо если хотите именно в вашем варианте, то:

```
driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "omlet-bar-login-button").click()
```

Я так понимаю, `By.CLASS_NAME` - это строковый параметр, его нужно указывать через запятую, а не вызывать как функцию.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Всё заработало! Счастья и успехов вам, я настолько рад. Господь благословит вас!

Answer (score 0):

Так как в этом случае строку вызвать невозможно, предлагаю вам заменить строку в **driver.get()** на переменную имеющую это же значение что было указано во время того момента, где там же находилась и строка! Думаю у вас сработает, у меня код успешно скомпилирован. Надеюсь и у вас сработает! -

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

url = "https://omlet.gg/stream/iromanenkov"

# Указываем абсолютный путь до хромдрайвера
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\namva\PycharmProjects\seleniumlessons\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")

try:
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    # Логин
    login = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME(" omlet-bar-login-button")).click()
    time.sleep(5)



except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! Спасибо за отклик, к сожалению ваш код не сработал, выдаёт всё ту же ошибку. Однако я немного подумал и решил сохранить значение " omlet-bar-login-button" в переменную "class_name" перед новоиспечённым "login = driver.find_element_by_class_name(class_name).click()" тут я убрал строковое значение и использовал переменную "class_name" в которую раннее сохранил строковое значение. Однако и это не сработало, теперь мне сообщает: 
Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
Заранее спасибо!